I can't get tampermonkey to activate on any page
I can't get tampermonkey to activate on any page.  This is my script.  Can anyone help?
// ==UserScript==
// @name         qbittorrent
// @namespace    http://hahnca.com
// @version      2024-12-27
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *github.com*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

 debugger;

 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("username").value = "testuser";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "testpwd";
}, false);



Go to chrome://extensions page and enable Developer mode in the top right corner, it's a nonsensical requirement of Google's ManifestV3. 2) Fix your @match, it must have all three parts (scheme, host, path) e.g. *://github.com/*


Thanks mucho. Working great.  I did have developer mode set. but the faq  examples had three parts but did not explicity say three parts were needed.
